# Use system proxy settings with authentication

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, proxy

How can I write my .NET application so that it can connect to HTTP servers through a system default proxy that requires authentication?

I'm using `HttpWebRequest` and I've tried this:

```
request.Proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
```

Doesn't have any effect. I can leave it away.

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Still no effect.

In app.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true"/>
  </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Also, nothing. Always HTTP error 407. Fiddler tells me that the client request has no authentication header at all, not even a wrong one.

What other options do I have?

My test environment is a .NET 4.0 application on Windows 10 and Fiddler local proxy with the option "Require Proxy Authentication". I know that the username and password are both "1" and this works in Internet Explorer. At first, IE asked for credentials, then I entered this and it could load pages. I did not check the "Save" option, but it remembers it anyway. Now I can't save it anymore because IE won't ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added in the proxy tag?

```
<defaultProxy>
      <proxy usesystemdefault="true"/>      
</defaultProxy>
```

This should push it to read the settings from IE.

Comment: It should read `"True"`, at least it says `"true"` is invalid. But still the error remains either way. So this does not help.